# Memory error when plotting large array with spyder

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, matplotlib

I have a problem while plotting big data on python 2.7, with spyder.

X, Y and Z are about 560,000 array length... which is a lot!

```
# ======
## plot:

fig = plt.figure("Map 3D couleurs")
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_trisurf(Xs, Ys, Zs, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0)
fig.colorbar(surf)

ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_zlabel("Z")
ax.set_title("Map 3D couleurs")

#ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5))
#ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(6))
#ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5))

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show();
```

Python reply this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 427, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 148, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 469, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1085, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 254, in draw
    for col in self.collections]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\art3d.py", line 580, in do_3d_projection
    PolyCollection.set_verts(self, segments_2d)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 842, in set_verts
    self._paths.append(mpath.Path(xy, codes))
MemoryError
```

Do you have an idea to solve this problem on python 2.7?
May be an other library, function... or stop using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the amount of detail from a length `560'000` array? If not, you could easily sub-sample the arrays, using for example:

```
n = 1000   # sample every n-th data point
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(Xs[::n], Ys[::n], Zs[::n], cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0)
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but do you know a library/function which could plot it easily?
May be it's a graphic card problem?

Comment: There aren't a lot of other plotting libraries for Python, so no... And I guess that any faster implementation will apply some simplification like the sub-sampling that I mentioned; creating a surface plot from half a million data points is simply expensive.

Answer (score -1):

try to read file partly and do not set data at once
for example put just one datum in a line
then read a tuple (x,y,z) and draw and repeat that